# Tassled Cap Transformation of Landsat-8 in ArcGIS using surface reflectance output from the USGS

Tags: envi, arcgis-10.5

I see lots of references for Tasseled Cap transformation for Landsat-8 Top of Atmosphere reflectance.  What I just got from Earth Explorer is a product called "surface reflectance", which sounds like it's atmospherically corrected and not the same product as the "top of atmosphere reflectance" product.

Should I re-order a different product?

Or, are there updated coefficients I might use for what I have?

Or (shudder), is there a tutorial on how the develop my own coefficients?